# Assignment problem with nonlinear constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

Consider $N$ different items and $M$ different slots.

$x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$ puts the $i$-th item into the $j$-th slots.

Each slot can hold $c_j$ items, i.e. $\sum_i x_{ij} \leq c_j \forall j$

And obviously I want to assign every item only once.

The hard bit is this constraint:

Every item has size $s_i$ and I want items of sufficiently different sizes in my slots. To be precise: i want for every two $x_.$ that $|s_k - s_l| \geq D$

How do I go about this, seems pretty nonlinear to me...

Is there a solver that can handle this for me?

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want to disallow assigning items $k$ and $\ell$ to the same slot if $|s_k-s_\ell| < D$.  You can enforce this with a "conflict" constraint for each such incompatible pair $k<\ell$ and slot $j$:
$$x_{k,j} + x_{\ell,j} \le 1. \tag1$$

Alternatively, you could impose
$$|s_k-s_\ell|\ge D(x_{k,j} + x_{\ell,j}-1) \tag2$$
for **all** $k<\ell$ and all $j$,
but a presolver would likely reduce $(2)$ to $(1)$ anyway.

Comment: I thought about that too but would that not quickly increase the number of equations to a point where the problem becomes practically unsolvable?
I expect about a couple of hundred items with enough slots of 3 to 5 to hold them all.

Comment: I recommend trying (1) and seeing how it does.  Many solvers store these type of constraints in a “conflict graph” and generate tighter “clique” constraints from them. If the direct approach of including (1) makes the problem too big, you can introduce these constraints dynamically only when they are violated (“row generation”).

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for a solver for this? I'm using google's OR tools most of the time but I don't see which one of them would handle this.

Comment: I work for SAS, which has a MILP solver (and many other solvers), as well as an algebraic modeling language, documented [here](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=ormpug&docsetTarget=titlepage.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en).  If you provide some sample data, I can try it out for you.

Comment: So this should work with most MILP solvers? How you I send data to you? Just post it here?

Comment: You can use any MILP solver, but performance varies greatly across implementations.  Yes, just post data here or add a link.